# Can I define a Typescript interface with computed keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, tsc

I want to define a Typescript interface with computed keys:

```js
const NAMESPACE = 'com.pizza'

const KEY_SAUCE = `${NAMESPACE}/sauce`
const KEY_CRUST = `${NAMESPACE}/crust`

interface PizzaToken {
  radius:      number
  [KEY_SAUCE]: Sauce
  [KEY_CRUST]: Crust
}

const pizza: PizzaToken = PizzaFactory.getToken(...)
console.log(pizza[KEY_SAUCE])
```

This design pattern gives me two unrelated Typescript errors; the first, on the interface:

```
TS1169: A computed property name in an interface must refer to an 
expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

and the second on the `pizza[KEY_SAUCE]`:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of 
type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Pizza'.
```

I can resolve these with some workarounds (e.g `Symbol`) but they're kind of clunky. What's the best way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `as const` to make a nonwidening string literal type at the key declarations:

```
const KEY_SAUCE = `${NAMESPACE}/sauce` as const;
const KEY_CRUST = `${NAMESPACE}/crust` as const;
```

Comment: Using Typescript 3.7.5, target "es2020", I get an error `TS1355: A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.` -- any suggestions?

Comment: If you're stuck on 3.7.5 then you can't use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  Suggestion: upgrade TypeScript and do it often since the language changes frequently.  The longer you wait to upgrade the worse it will be when you do.